# gitlab CI is not creating kube config in users home folder

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci, azure-aks

I have Gitlab CI pipeline in which I am creating Azure kubernetes cluster using terraform scripts.
After creating kubernetes cluster, I need kube config so that I can connect to cluster.

I am running following command to create the kube config :

```
$ az aks get-credentials --resource-group test1 --name k8stest --overwrite-existing
Merged "k8stest" as current context in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.kube\config
Cleaning up file based variables
```

instead of users home folder , it is creating kube config in some `systemprofile` folder

how can I restrict gitlab to create kube config in users home folder ONLY ?

Comment: please suggest . it is blocker